# Android audio streaming: anybody managed to make android-openmxplayer working?

Tags: java, android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I am looking for a library to replace the buggy Android MediaPlayer library.

I was investigating [android-openmxplayer](https://code.google.com/p/android-openmxplayer/).

I am able to launch the project, but can't stream any online live mp3.

Has anybody managed to make this project work? Does anyone use this library?

Answer (score 2):

Try [aacdecoder-android](https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/) library. I used it in one my project in which I needed to stream audio-stream and it's works perfect for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this library but what about the legal aspects ? Do you pay the patent fees mentioned here : http://www.vialicensing.com/licensing/aac-fees.aspx ? See also the warning on the page you mention "PLEASE NOTE that the use of this software may require the payment of patent royalties. You need to consider this issue before you start building derivative works. We are not warranting or indemnifying you in any way for patent royalities! YOU ARE SOLELY RESPONSIBLE FOR YOUR OWN ACTIONS!". Thanks for your feedback on these legal issues.